# Map on data node is run by whom?

Tags: hadoop

I faced this tricky question in one of my interviews.

Question was

> Who run map on data node ?

Answer is neither ***Job tracker*** nor ***task tracker***.

Could anybody help me please

Answer (score 0):

`Datanodes` do not run any task, they are part of `HDFS` and take care of storing data.

So "map on data node" makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. May be your interpretation of the question could be right. I am not sure though :)..

Answer (score 0):

if hadoop 1.x is installed on the system then If task tracker is running on the same data node then task tracker daemon is the one who would run the map task after getting instruction from job tracker .

if no task tracker is running on the data node then no map task can run on that node , data node takes care of storage part it has nothing to do with map processing .

if hadoop 2.x then application master is the entity which does so by coordinating with node manager and resource manager.

Comment: Thank you! Even i told similar answer. But the interviewer told me its neither Job tracker nor Task tracker.... I am not sure what he meant